# howto call makefile in sub-directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a developing project, and use another lib project source code, and it has its own makefile to produce the lib file. how to write my project makefile to call another makefile?

```
myproject/
  -makefile 
  src/

  threePartyLibProject/
         -makefile
         src/
         inc/
```

how to writing my project makefile to call the threePartyLibProject makefile, and how link to its produced libs?

very highly appreciated your help,

thanks very much.

Comment: i agree with @perreal , also you can try this ..... `cd $(your_directory) && $(MAKE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-C` switch in myproject.makefile for [recursive make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html):

```
threePartyLibProject:
             $(MAKE) -C threePartyLibProject
```

Answer (score 2):

your makefile should look like this.

```
all: threePartyLibProject
threePartyLibProject:
[TAB] $(MAKE) -C threePartyLibProject

.PHONY: threePartyLibProject
```